# heap corruption in custom string class

Tags: c++, string

So as I'm creating my own string class using smart pointers (so I can get accustomed to them), and it has mostly been going well, except for the operator+() function.

It keeps crashing the program, and when VS debugs the program, the destructor is throwing an exception. I can't seem to pinpoint why, this is the only function causing the program to crash, even when I remove all of the algorithms, and simply return a `mystring` object.

Any suggestions?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <memory>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

class mystring {
public:
    mystring() : word(make_unique<char[]>('\0')), len(0) {}
    ~mystring() { cout << "goodbye objects!";}
    mystring(const char *message) : word(make_unique<char[]>(strlen(message) + 1)), len(strlen(message)) {
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) word[i] = message[i];
        word[len] = '\0';
    }
    mystring(const mystring &rhs) : word(make_unique<char[]>(rhs.len)), len(rhs.len + 1) {
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) word[i] = rhs.word[i];
        word[len] = '\0';
    }
    mystring &operator=(const mystring &rhs) {
        if (this != &rhs) {
            releaseWord();
            word = make_unique<char[]>(rhs.len + 1);
            len = rhs.len;
            for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) word[i] = rhs.word[i];
            word[len] = '\0';
        }
        return *this;
    }

    //what is wrong with this function/what should be changed?
    friend mystring operator+(const mystring& lhs, const mystring& rhs) {
        mystring Result;

        int lhsLength = lhs.len, rhsLength = rhs.len;

        Result.releaseWord();
        Result.word = make_unique<char[]>(lhsLength + rhsLength + 1);
        Result.len = lhsLength + rhsLength;
        for (int i = 0; i < lhsLength; i++) Result.word[i] = lhs.word[i];
        for (int j = lhsLength; j < Result.len; j++) Result.word[j] = rhs.word[j];
        Result.word[Result.len] = '\0';


        return Result;
    }

    friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &os, const mystring &message) {
        return os << message.word.get();
    }
    int size() const {
        return len;
    }
private:
    int len;
    unique_ptr<char[]> word;
    void releaseWord() {
        char *temp = word.release();
        delete[] temp;
    }
};

int main()
{
    mystring word1 = "Darien", word2 = "Miller", word3;

    cout << word1 + word2;//causes heap corruption
    word3 = word1 + word2; //causes heap corruption

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In some places (like the copy constructor and the default constructor) you forgot to leave space for the null terminator. Note that `make_unique<char[]>('\0')` allocates zero bytes because `'\0'` is just another way of writing 0.

Comment: ahhh, ok, that makes perfect sense. Would it be if I did something like this instead?

    mystring() : len(0), word(make_unique<char[]>(1)) {
        word[0] = '\0';
        }

Answer (score 1):

Problem in this line:

```
for (int j = lhsLength; j < Result.len; j++) Result.word[j] = rhs.word[j];
```

j is wrong for `rhs.word[j];`

Should be something like `rhs.word[j-lhsLength];`

you are busting the array limits

Comment: Also, is better if your operator= returns a const mystring&, but that doesn't appear to be your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your `operator+` is not copying characters from `rhs` correctly, because it is using the wrong index to iterate through `rhs.word[]`. It should look like this instead:

```
friend mystring operator+(const mystring& lhs, const mystring& rhs) {
    mystring Result;
    int lhsLength = lhs.len, rhsLength = rhs.len;
    Result.word = make_unique<char[]>(lhsLength + rhsLength + 1);
    Result.len = lhsLength + rhsLength;
    for (int i = 0; i < lhsLength; i++)
        Result.word[i] = lhs.word[i];
    for (int i = lhsLength, j = 0; i < Result.len; i++, j++)
        Result.word[i] = rhs.word[j];
    Result.word[Result.len] = '\0';
    return Result;
}
```

An alternative option is to use `std::copy_n()` instead of a manual loop:

```
#include <algorithm>

friend mystring operator+(const mystring& lhs, const mystring& rhs) {
    mystring Result;
    Result.word = make_unique<char[]>(lhs.len + rhs.len + 1);
    Result.len = lhs.len + rhs.len;
    std::copy_n(lhs.word.get(), lhs.len, Result.word.get());
    std::copy_n(rhs.word.get(), rhs.len, Result.word.get() + lhs.len);
    Result.word[Result.len] = '\0';
    return Result;
}
```

Also, your default and copy constructors are not setting up the members correctly (for instance, your copy constructor is not allocating enough room for a null terminator, and is setting `len` to include the null terminator).

And, your `ReleaseWord` method is unnecessary, and you should consider implementing move semantics as well.

Try something more like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <memory>
#include <cstring>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

class mystring {
public:
    mystring() : len(0), word(make_unique<char[]>(1)) {
        word[0] = '\0';
    }

    ~mystring() {
        cout << "goodbye objects!";
    }

    mystring(const char *message) : len(strlen(message)), word(make_unique<char[]>(len + 1)) {
        copy_n(message, len, word.get());
        word[len] = '\0';
    }

    mystring(const mystring &rhs) : len(rhs.len), word(make_unique<char[]>(len + 1)) {
        copy_n(rhs.word.get(), rhs.len, word.get());
        word[len] = '\0';
    }

    mystring(mystring &&rhs) : len(rhs.len), word(std::move(rhs.word)) {
    }

    mystring& operator=(const mystring &rhs) {
        if (this != &rhs) {
            mystring tmp(rhs);
            swap(word, tmp.word);
            swap(len, tmp.len);
        }
        return *this;
    }

    mystring& operator=(mystring &&rhs) {
        swap(word, rhs.word);
        swap(len, rhs.len);
        return *this;
    }

    friend mystring operator+(const mystring& lhs, const mystring& rhs) {
        mystring Result;
        Result.len = lhs.len + rhs.len;
        Result.word = make_unique<char[]>(Result.len + 1);
        std::copy_n(lhs.word.get(), lhs.len, Result.word.get());
        std::copy_n(rhs.word.get(), rhs.len, Result.word.get() + lhs.len);
        Result.word[Result.len] = '\0';
        return Result;
    }

    friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &os, const mystring &message) {
        return os << message.word.get();
    }

    int size() const {
        return len;
    }

private:
    int len;
    unique_ptr<char[]> word;
};
```

Comment: This was very helpful, thank you!! Also, looking through your solution, I've noticed a few parts that were new to me, with this block of code in particular:

    `mystring(mystring &&rhs) : len(rhs.len), word(std::move(rhs.word)) {
    }`

What's the purpose of this function, as well as the double "&"? Thanks!

Comment: @DarienMiller it is a move constructor, which transfers ownership of existing allocated memory instead of allocating new memory. Read up about "rvalue references" and "move semantics", which were added in C++11 (you are clearly using C++14 or later since you are using `std::make_unique()`, which was added in C++14).